# No content in <app-root> element in browser using the command "node app.js"

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular7

I created an Angular 7 application using the Angular CLI. I added my express server as one knows it. Afterwards I used the command "node server/app.js to start my app, but then in the browser in the "Elements" section there appears `<app-root></app-root>` without any content. As if the browser knew nothing about the actual Angular application. And when I run the `ng serve` command it seems to know about the actual Angular application, but there appears a 404 not found error in terms of post and get requests to the data server.

I already had a working Angular4 application with -I guess- the same setup and now same things seem to not work any longer.
I researched all day long to find the solution but for nothing.

I think it is not advantageous to post all my files in here. Comment if I was wrong and I am going to edit them.
Thanks in advance.

My `app.js`:

```js
"use strict";
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

// import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var app = express();
app.use(cors());

const router = express.Router();

var nodeModulesPath = path.join(__dirname, "..", "node_modules");
app.use("/node_modules", express.static(nodeModulesPath));
var srcPath = path.join(__dirname, "..", "src");
app.use("/src", express.static(srcPath));
var serverPath = path.join(__dirname);
app.use("/server", express.static(serverPath));

// app.use(bodyParser.json());

var models = require("./models");
models.sequelize.sync({force:true}).then(function() {
  console.log("TABELLE ERSTELLT");
  // app.use(cors());
  app.use("/", router);


  app.use(bodyParser
    .urlencoded({extended:true})
  );
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  console.log("after bodyparser");


  app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "views", "index.html"));
  });
  // app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  //   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "views", "index.html"));
  // });

  app.post("/goals/create",function (req, res){
    models.Goal.create({
        id: req.body.id,
        name: req.body.name,
        content: req.body.content,
        firstGivenValue: req.body.firstGivenValue,
        fittingValue: req.body.fittingValue,
        someone_would_like_to_implement: req.body.someone_would_like_to_implement,
        i_know_how_to_implement_it: req.body.i_know_how_to_implement_it

    }).then(function(obj){
        console.log(obj.id);
        // res.end("erfolgreich");
        res.redirect("/");
    })
    console.log(req.body);
  });
  app.get("/test",(req, res) => {
    res.end("test erfolgreich");
  });

  app.listen(3000);
});
```

Comment: It may help if you add the contents of `server/app.js` so we can see how you're serving the angular app

Comment: read this https://blog.cloudboost.io/run-your-angular-app-on-nodejs-c89f1e99ddd3

Comment: Okay, not sure why you're serving up the contents of `node_modules` as static resources. Also, make sure you're serving the built version of the Angular code, i.e. the version that is placed in `dist` when you run `ng build`, not the version in `src`

Comment: @user184994 . Okay, thank you so far for answering. But how exactly do I serve the version that is placed in `dist` ? Sorry, I am new to this ^^ I mean I run `node server/app.js` and nothing concerning the `src` folder. I don't know what to do yet.

Comment: Take a look at the link above that was posted by @RezaRahmati

Comment: @user184994 I followed RezaRahmati 's post's instructions, but I still have my problems.

Comment: Mind explicitly adding the error message or some kind of log outpu?

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you think it used to work for angular 4. Currently you're serving the index.html from the src folder. That's not going to work, your app is a typescript app and will need to be compiled one way or another; not to mention the Angular compiler. In the early days (I think pre 4, but not sure) angular serve also write the served files in a folder in your project, so you could just pick those JIT compiled files up and toss them on a web server, or express server. Those days are gone (with good reason for that matter, mostly performance).

You will now have to create an explicit build (ng build) and tell your express server (app.js) to target your dist folder.

TL;DR:

Run `ng build`

Replace

```
var srcPath = path.join(__dirname, "..", "src");
app.use("/src", express.static(srcPath));
```

With:

```
var distPath = path.join(__dirname, "..", "dist");
app.use("/dist", express.static(distPath));
```

Comment: Thanks so far. I did the following so far: Replaced the code as mentioned. Run ng build after that. But I still have my problems. BTW in my terminal there appear the created tables of my database when running `node server/app.js`. So this works out so far. And what means "TL;DR:?"

Comment: Too long, didn't read ;). You should run the ng build before starting the node server I'd say; but my node knowledge ran out here.